Are the Sigma functions in SHA-256 invertible?
If they are invertible, why are they used? Is it just for bit diffusion and to increase the amount of correlation between the bits, and thus increase "confusion" in the internal state?

The definitions of the $\Sigma$ and $\sigma$ functions of SHA-256 are in FIPS 186-4 section 4.1.2. If this is homework: write them as a 32x32 bit matrix multiplication.

@fgrieu I know, I have a huge interest in cryptography and high performance computing, but I am really not that good at math. Could you maybe write a short answer to the question, not that convoluted, explaining how I would go about inverting it?

It's not complicated. Line $\ell$, column $c$ of the matrix tells if bit $c$ of the input of the function influences bit $\ell$ of it's output. There are three bits 1 per line for $Σ$ and two or three for $σ$ (because the later uses SHR). Invertibility of the function is equivalent to invertibility of the matrix, which can be determined by computing it's discriminant. I suggest that you edit the answer to solve at least the "invertible?" part of the question.
